# Dropdown list selection not working properly in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have various dropdown lists, in a way that if we select first item should not show in second dropdown list for that I have written jquery like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ddlProjectvalue').change(function() {
        updateDDLValues();       
    });
});

function updateDDLValues() {
    // Display all
    $('.ddlProjectvalue option').show();
    // Hide all selected options from other selectlists
    $('.ddlProjectvalue').each(function(i,element) {
        var selectedvalue = $(element).find('option:selected').val();
        $('.ddlProjectvalue').not(element).find('option[value="'+selectedvalue+'"]').hide();
    });    
}
```

as you can check [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Pt7qV/2/), it is working fine in chrome and firefox but not working in internet explorer, what is the problem?

Comment: which version of IE are you using?

Comment: Aheumm... not working in chrome either... (Mavericks, V34)

Comment: It works on firefox though

Comment: not working on safari

Comment: Is there any alternative option as same process?

Comment: What are you trying? Doesn't make sense to override default functionality of native elements.

Comment: You can check [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Pt7qV/2/), as you can understand, what is actual requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Function is working Fine for Me in Only for Internet Explorer

```
function updateDDLValues() {
// Display all
$('.ddlProjectvalue span option').unwrap();
   // Hide all selected options from other selectlists
    $('.ddlProjectvalue').each(function (i, element) {
    var selectedvalue = $(element).find('option:selected').val();
    $('.ddlProjectvalue').not(element).find('option[value="' + selectedvalue + '"]').wrap('<span style="display: none;">');
});
}
```

OR

```
function updateDDLValues() {
$('.ddlProjectvalue span option').unwrap().show();
 // Hide all selected options from other selectlists
  $('.ddlProjectvalue').each(function (i, element) {
   var selectedvalue = $(element).find('option:selected').val();
   $('.ddlProjectvalue').not(element).find('option[value="' + selectedvalue + '"]').wrap('<span>').hide();
                });
}
```

If we want to use other than I E, we can approach My above  code(In My question) which was not supported by IE.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that most browsers don't allow the hiding of an <option>. I think the way to go is to remove the <option> altogether.

Comment: Is there any alternate option?

Comment: The other option (better IMHO) is to rebuild the whole option list of all the dropdowns except the one that changed.

Answer (score 1):

i have found the problem, `$(element).find('option:selected').val()` in this line element is coming as undefined in IE whereas in chrome proper value is coming

Comment: Yes, it should be $(element).val()

Comment: solution for this?? How can we fix it?